# How can I convert a Pandas DataFrame of vectors and labels into input for an RNN in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, text-classification

I'm working on a text classifier using an LSTM in TensorFlow and can't figure out the format of the input data.
My input data is a Pandas Dataframe with one feature column and one label column.

My feature column is a 2D array representing an array of vectors and my label column is a String, an example of my data input is below.

How do I convert this Dataframe into a dataset that can be used as input to be used in a Tensorflow.Keras model?

I've tried converting the Dataframe into a TensorFlow.Dataset dataset using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices but this produces a TypeError

```py
##Building input data
test01 = ([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]],'label1')
test02 = ([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]],'label2')
test03 = ([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]],'label3')
test04 = ([[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]],'label1')
test_data = [test01,test02,test03,test04]


##DataFrame from data
columns = ['feature','label']
t_df = pd.DataFrame(data = test_data, columns = columns)
```

```py
##Convert to TensorFlow Dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((t_df['feature'], t_df['label']))
```

This produces the following error:

```py
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

```py
##TensorFlow Model Example 
model = tf.keras.Sequential([,
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(input_shape),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you want to create dataset specifically from dataframe of from a csv file? If latter, TF has `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` just for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you just passed slightly wrong dimensions. `from_tensor_slices` expects a list of objects, not a nested list.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([i for i in t_df['feature']], t_df['label']))
```